# How to get react to update when calling a method from JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a table in my jsx that renders a league table. I want to now show the "form" of each team. i.e. the last 5 games.

I have a method that works this out (called form)

```
 const LeagueTable = ({ teams, form }) => (
  <table className="leagueTable">
    <thead>
      <tr className="tableRow">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>P</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>L</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>GD</th>
        <th>Pts</th>
        <th>Form</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {teams.sort((a, b) => (
          (b.points) - (a.points)
      )).map((team, index) => (
        <tr key={index} className="tableRow">
         <td className="stats">{index + 1}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.name}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.won + team.lost + team.drawn}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.won}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.drawn}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.lost}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.goalsScored}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.goalsAgainst}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.goalsScored - team.goalsAgainst}</td>
         <td className="stats">{team.points}</td>
         <td className="stats">{form(team)}</td>
       </tr>
     ))}
    </tbody>
 </table>
);
```

this is the method:

```
 form = (team) => {
    let lastFiveMatches;
    return team && team.matches ?
      lastFiveMatches = Object.values(this.props.teams.find(t => t.name === team.name).matches).sort(this.compare).reverse().slice(0, 5).map((match) => {
        if(match.winner === team.name){
          return 'W ';
        }
        else if(match.winner !== team.name){
          return 'L ';
        }
        else {
          return 'D ';
        }
      })
    :
    '---'
  }
```

basically it all works but since adding this method to my table, it only updates my table on refresh rather than instantly (which is what it was doing before)

can anyone explain why it is doing this and how I can change it back?

when I get rid of `<td className="stats">{form(team)}</td>` it instantly works again so I know this method call is the problem

I have tried adding `this.forceUpdate()` and `this.setState(this.state)` to force a re-render but it looks like this causes react to blow up and I get the `cannot update during an existing state transition` error.

Comment: @DaveNewton nah it's working coz I pass it down as props

Comment: sorry to be clear, it's not broken. my issue is I have to refresh to get it working since ive added a method to jsx rather than updating instantly and i was wondering why it does this and how to fix this

Comment: Please share the whole code you have. I dont understand where is "form" from? is it in another module? or inside the container? because I see you have there "this.props.teams"

Comment: Calling `setState` in render isn't best practice.
If your `team` prop is changing and being passed from a `parent component` then calling `setState()` within the `parent component` will call `render` of that parent and subsequently re render the `child` template with the new `team` prop.

Comment: @TzookBarNoy I have added the League Table component. anything else you want to see? basically I have a Main Component and I pass the props to the league table component

Comment: @FrancisLeigh I have a Main component that passes props to the League table component including the passing of this function. I then update the table it calls the function but nothing appears on screen till I refresh

Comment: @TheWalrus Ah, gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are adding this `form` function will cause you a lot of pain.

Even though you are saying it works, the `this.props...` inside the function is not valid.

If you want it to work, what I would do is:

you will need to define `compare` and not reference `this` inside the function

```
const compare = ()=>{'whatever'}
```

the form code:

```
const form = (team, teams) => {
    let lastFiveMatches;
    return team && team.matches ?
      lastFiveMatches = Object.values(teams.find(t => t.name === team.name).matches).sort(compare).reverse().slice(0, 5).map((match) => {
        if(match.winner === team.name){
          return 'W ';
        }
        else if(match.winner !== team.name){
          return 'L ';
        }
        else {
          return 'D ';
        }
      })
    :
    '---'
  }
```

and now how to use it in your table:

```
<td className="stats">{form(team, teams)}</td>
```

make your functions clean and not dependent on specific `this` or scopes.
You could bind the specific scope, but that is not something you would like to do.

---

Update:
After reviewing the code, as I thought it was the scope issue

Please add a constructor to the component that contains the 'form' method and inside it

```
 this.form = this.form.bind(this)
```

Or you can use ES6 instead
On table props:

```
 <Table
          teams={teams}
          form={team=> this.form(team)}
        />
```

Comment: sorry, you say it's not valid but it works fine? I'm getting it as props from redux. 
my problem isn't that it's broken, it's that it doesn't re render the dom when I would like it to, it requires a browser refresh

Comment: Scopes are easy to manipulate but can cause some pain especially with react. I don't see how you get those props from redux in to that function. If you could share all the code I could help

Comment: Yap for sure please

Comment: https://github.com/RichMatthews/redux-league, there it is. to run it: `npm i > npm start, then in another tab, npm run watch`

Comment: ok I see your changes but my form method is an arrow function so is automatically bound to its class. and sorry but I don't see how this would solve the no re render problem?

Comment: well ran your code, and you have an error on adding a new game. The error: "index.js:35990 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'winner' of undefined"  your 'matches' array contains "undefined" so you should go check your code on why you have it.

Comment: yeh I've seen that error but that is not affecting my issue here. but anyway thanks!